# How to bind TextField and ProgressBar in JavaFx

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to Use reactive bindings to bind the value of `alcoholPercentageField` to the progress property of `alcoholBar`.
The progress bar will "full" when alcoholic content is set to 20 % and empty when the alcoholic content is 0

My Code-

```
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.setTitle("Mead calculator");

    // Creating the fields and components
    TextField waterAmountField = new TextField();

    TextField alcoholPercentageField = new TextField();

    TextField sugarAmountField = new TextField();
    Label meadTotalAmount = new Label();
    Label assessmentLabel = new Label("");
    //assessmentLabel.textProperty().bind(alcoholPercentageField.textProperty());

    //Conditional Binding Error 

    assessmentLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.when((alcoholPercentageField.textProperty().lessThan(5))).then("Smart").otherwise("Bad"));

    ProgressBar alcoholBar = new ProgressBar();

    //Error is here
    alcoholBar.progressProperty().bind(alcoholPercentageField.textProperty() * 5);
```

Rest of the Code: some visual things

```
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));
    var columnOneConstraints = new ColumnConstraints(150, 150, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    columnOneConstraints.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);
    var columnTwoConstrains = new ColumnConstraints(200,200, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    columnTwoConstrains.setHgrow(Priority.SOMETIMES);
    grid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(columnOneConstraints, columnTwoConstrains);
    alcoholBar.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    GridPane.setColumnSpan(alcoholBar, 2);
    GridPane.setHalignment(assessmentLabel, HPos.RIGHT);
    sugarAmountField.setDisable(true);

    grid.add(new Label("Water (l):"), 0, 0);
    grid.add(waterAmountField, 1, 0);
    
    grid.add(new Label("Vol-%:"), 0, 1);
    grid.add(alcoholPercentageField, 1, 1);

    grid.add(new Label("Sugar (kg):"),  0, 2);
    grid.add(sugarAmountField, 1, 2);

    grid.add(new Label("Lemons: "), 0, 3);
    grid.add(new Label("To taste"), 1, 3);

    grid.add(new Label("Mead total (kg):"), 0, 4);
    grid.add(meadTotalAmount, 1, 4);

    grid.add(alcoholBar, 0, 5);
    grid.add(assessmentLabel, 1, 6);
    // Okay, layout creation stops here
    
    
    // And of course set the scene and show the stage as always
    stage.setScene(new Scene(grid, 500, 400));
    stage.show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create some additional Property and Binding objects.

First, create properties for your TextField `alcoholPercentageField`. Then, you'll bind them using a StringConverter to convert the text entered into doubles.

Finally, use [bindBidirectional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#bindBidirectional-javafx.beans.property.Property-javafx.beans.property.Property-java.text.Format-) to propagate and lastly bind it with progressBar by dividing 20 ( The progress bar will be "full" when alcoholic content is set to 20 %)

Code Will be like this-

```
    // Properties used for bindings
    DoubleProperty alcoholPercent = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    //Setup the converters to get the input from the textfields
    StringConverter<? extends Number> converter = new DoubleStringConverter();
    
    Bindings.bindBidirectional(alcoholPercentageField.textProperty(), alcoholPercent, (StringConverter<Number>) converter);
    alcoholBar.progressProperty().bind(alcoholPercent.divide(20));
```

> For Conditional Binding, check this [Conditional Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572889/conditional-binding)
>
> > Code would be like this-

```
    assessmentLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.when(alcoholPercent.lessThan(5)).then("Smart").otherwise("Bad"));
    assessmentLabel.textFillProperty().bind(Bindings.when(alcoholPercent.lessThan(5)).then(Color.GREEN).otherwise(Color.RED));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Bindings API](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/package-summary.html).

Note that the progress is supposed to be between 0 and 1, so if you are entering percentages, instead of proportions, into your text field you need to divide by 100:

```
alcoholBar.progressProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
    () -> 0.05 * Double.parseDouble(alcoholPercentageField.getText()),
    alcoholPercentageField.textProperty()
));
```

You might want to implement more complex logic to, e.g. check for a valid number, or at least non-empty text field.

Comment: For every input(1,2,3....) it's filling the full progress bar. Eg. It should fill 50% when the input is 10 and Full fill when it is 20.

Comment: @Himu See update.

Comment: I'm trying to implement conditional binding on this line (see edited code) `assessmentLabel.textProperty().bind(alcoholPercentageField.textProperty());`  and my approach is `assessmentLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.when((alcoholPercentageField.textProperty().lessThan(5))).then("Smart").otherwise("Bad"));`  

Problem is textProperty is String but I need to compare with a int value.

Comment: @Himu That's really a whole different question. However, consider using a `TextFormatter<Number>` on the text field. Then you can bind to the formatter's `value` property instead of the text.